# How to build a pep8 like static analysis tool for Django?

Tags: python, django, static-analysis

There are tools like pyflakes and pep8.py, which tell you if the code you have written meets certain standards. I want to build a similar tool which does static analysis on Django and tells things when they dont meet standards. (Eg models should have a `__unicode__`.)
Questions:

- Is it worth doing this? (Are there enough common things which an be tested for?)
- Is there a good starting point? (Eg some app I can contribute to instead of starting my own.)
- How do I proceed? (Eg. is using ast module a good idea for this?)

Comment: A similar question was asked recently, but rather less well, so the answers only cover some of your points.

Comment: pylint claims to support plugins, so perhaps you could try that.  But don't start from scratch.  Pick a tool like pylint, pyflakes, or pep8.py and extend them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two open source projects that I know of which do this type of analysis speficially for Django:

- [django-lint](https://chris-lamb.co.uk/projects/django-lint/) which is a wrapper/extension to PyLint
- [djangolint](http://djangolint.com/) which is a Django Dash project which appears to have it's own set of analyizers

Either one should provide a solid starting point for what you are looking to do.